# Google mini ignoring sitemap

Tags: sitemap, google-search-appliance

I'm in the processing of setting up a Google Mini device to index an ASP.Net site which has a lot of dynamically generated content. I've created a dynamic site.map XML file which lists all of the dynamic URL's. This conforms to the [XML site map format](http://www.sitemaps.org/) and is currently being indexed by Google but seems to be ignored by the Google mini device.

I've added the site.map file into the "Start crawling from the following URL's". When I view the crawl diagnostics the site.map file comes up but none of the dynamic URL's contained within the site.map are being indexed. The Google mini device is only indexing 100 URL's whereas the site.map contains 10,000.

If I search for a phrase using the test centre the search results includes the site.map and not the URL it points to.

Any ideas?

Comment: this might be a better question for Server Fault. Agree? If so, please flag this and I'll migrate it.

Comment: I actually tried there first but without any luck.  I was hoping the larger stackoverflow audience may have had some experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've just had a consultant come in who has stated the Google Mini cannot index the URL's contained in a sitemap.xml file.  One alternative solution is to create a HTML page with all of the links within it.